# Trouble fetching json data with google api on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api

I am trying to fetch json from the adsense api using this code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2Authentication.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self signInToGoogle];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//Creat your Google APP here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and get the key and secret

#define GoogleClientID    @"xxxxxxxxx"
#define GoogleClientSecret @"xxxxxxxxx"
#define GoogleAuthURL   @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
#define GoogleTokenURL  @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"


- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * )authForGoogle
{
    //This URL is defined by the individual 3rd party APIs, be sure to read their documentation

    NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:GoogleTokenURL];
    // We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
    // the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
    // loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page. This needs to match the URI set as the
    // redirect URI when configuring the app with Instagram.
    NSString * redirectURI = @"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"lifebeat"
                                                             tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                          redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                             clientID:GoogleClientID
                                                         clientSecret:GoogleClientSecret];
    auth.scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense";
    return auth;
}


- (void)signInToGoogle
{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [self authForGoogle];

    // Display the authentication view
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                                                authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GoogleAuthURL]
                                                                                                keychainItemName:@"GoogleKeychainName"
                                                                                                        delegate:self
                                                                                                finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}


- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth
                 error:(NSError * )error
{
    NSLog(@"finished");
    NSLog(@"auth access token: %@", auth.accessToken);

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:NO];
    if (error != nil) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Google"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success Authorizing with Google"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.1/reports"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


    if(jsonData != nil)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        if (error == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
    }
}

@end
```

I log in to google fine on the app and get a popup saying success, but as that is happening my nslog is showing this

```
2013-06-14 19:28:51.681 Simple-OAuth2[9253:c07] finished
2013-06-14 19:28:51.681 Simple-OAuth2[9253:c07] auth access token: ya29.xxxxxxxxxx
2013-06-14 19:28:51.912 Simple-OAuth2[9253:c07] {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Login Required";
                reason = required;
            }
        );
        message = "Login Required";
    };
}
```

How do I stay logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the parameters to access the data. Check below links that will help.

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/standard_params
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.1/reference/reports/generate

O-Auth token and API Key will be necessary to get a response.